# Google map from server side to post on ejs page

Tags: node.js, google-maps, embedded-javascript

How can you show a Google map on an ejs page when you call it from server side, I can do it directly on the index page but need to figure out how to use the data I grabbed from server side to create the markers on the map. Tx

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable and use the [`Google Maps Embed API`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start) and make sure to have your link in an iframe div. `Google Maps Embed API` maps are easy to add to your web page. Just set the `URL` you build as the value of an iframe's `src` attribute. Control the size of the map with the iframe's `height` and `width` attributes. No JavaScript required:

The URL for an Google Maps Embed API request is as follows:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/MODE?key=YOUR_API_KEY&parameters
```

All requests to the Google Maps Embed API must include a free API key as the value of a `key` parameter. Your key enables you to monitor your application's Maps API usage and ensures that Google can contact you about your application if necessary.